# Hide URL name, but still have a link to it

Tags: ip, url

### Goal

Suppose **I have original web page** hosted on an URL like

```
www.mywebsite.com/page
```

I want people accessing this webpage **thinking they are visiting other URL** like

```
www.anotherwebiste/page
```

Is it possible? If so, how to achieve this?

### What's not working

- I considered **finding the IP address of original website**, but that doesn't seem to be doing the trick.
- **URL shorteners** just forward to the *real URL* `www.mywebsite.com/page`

Comment: You need to find someone to run a reverse proxy for you.

Comment: Why was it downvoted?

Comment: @skrco: I didn't downvote, but most likely the reason is because this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/167586). You've said what you want, but not why you want it. So there's no way anyone can give you a sensible answer to how you can get what you really want. You think hiding the URL will do something, but never say what that something is. If it won't do what you want, or there's a better way to do what you think that will do, we can't tell. (That, or the fact that it's not about software or hardware.)

Comment: @skrco For the record, I want to do it to maintain privacy.

Comment: @capcom: Privacy of what? If that's what you want, just pick a website name that gives no information like "wehroihwyeothgq.com".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't think it's a XY problem. It's Proof Of Concept question regarding networking. I would rather edit the question, giving 1) what is to be achieved - fake underlying url and 2) a starting point - capcom's urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, even in principle.

If your server has a public entry in the DNS (Domain Name System), it effectively says the following:

"this IP address x.x.x.x refers to the domain a.b.c" (oversimplified; sometimes there are further levels of subdomain, and IPv6, etc.)

Since the DNS is publicly queryable, and can be done both ways (IP address to domain name or domain name to IP address), then by creating a DNS entry for your IP address, you essentially gave away that information to the whole world for free.

**Assuming you own the server in question**, if you **completely remove** your server's IP address from the DNS system, that is the only way to disassociate your server from having any domain name. If you do that, your server will still be addressable via its IP address, but not by any domain name, because no mapping between domain names and IP addresses will exist in the DNS system if you remove it.

If you don't own the server, there's absolutely nothing you can do.

The reason why this doesn't work is because, whenever a computer establishes a network connection, it is "observable": both the client and the server can see the IP address of the endpoint they're communicating with; this is the means by which they tell the network where to send their packets to. Once you have the IP address of an endpoint, that's all the info you need to perform a reverse DNS query on it and detect which domain(s) resolve to that IP address.

The only way to do this, which isn't really "a way", is to have your page/content hosted elsewhere.

For example, if you have http://example.com/content.html, and you have that page hosted in its entirety at some other website http://example2.com/content.html, then no one will be aware of the "real" address of the page http://example.com/content.html if you give out the link to example2. But that is *indirection* and does not allow clients to *directly* connect to your server/website. As soon as they directly connect to you, they've got your domain name (if you have one). Period.

Comment: I would add that if you have access to DNS zone you can set masked DNS forward as you've stated, without the need to own the server or having a root access.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and bought another domain. Just waiting for it to propagate, but otherwise, everything should be good.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, but the obvious implementation would require a website offering the service.  I don't know if such such websites exist.

Here's how it could be done.  All it takes is an anonymizing combination of [TinyURL](http://tinyurl.com) functionality allowing you to associate your hidden link to a published link together with [Anonymouse](http://anonymouse.org/anonwww.html) functionality that fetches pages for you, but in this case, hiding the identity of the site it fetches rather than your identity.

Even though it's technically possible, it seems unlikely it could be successful as a business, which could be why I don't know of any.  The problem is that if the thing is guaranteeing up front to take to someplace it'll never tell you, why would you go there?  It seems likely every AV software maker would instantly block the site.  I just don't see it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can try UUEncoding the address, but it is still very easy to find the DNS name you are connecting to, even if you're using just an IP address. Because of that, I'm going to say that no solution is going to work 100% for your question